# Facebook integration... Where to start?

Tags: django, facebook

I recently put a django project of mine into its beta stages and would really like to integrate more with social media, particularly facebook.

Now there are so many facebook integrations out there... I don't know where to start but, I'll tell you what I am after.

My sites publishes content with photos and also user related data (which site doesn't)

on each individual page I already have a facebook like button that basically has the absolute url of that page

so for instance:

```
http://my-site.com/url-1
http://my-site.com/url-345345
http://my-site.com/url-456456456
```

When a user `likes` this particular url I would like them to become a Fan on my facebook site/page as well.

I also added the FB opengraph tool which is a bit more informative once a user likes it. But it still does not publish any statistics to my page.

Can someone give me a bit of an understanding on what the best option is for this type of integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a security option for the user, Facebook has never allowed third party access to "become a fan."

If you want to record locally when someone presses the "Like" button, you'll have to implement it locally (copy the presentation, and query Facebook yourself), so you can intercept the event.  I've done that; it's not too hard.

I suggest you review the Connect Terms of Service to see what it is you're allowed to do: http://developers.facebook.com/policy/